# jquery .animate() marginTop keeps expanding document height

Tags: jquery-animate

Check out my fiddle to see what I'm working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/ETKYj/7/

It expands the height until the end of the duration, tripling the size of the page.  I want the words to animate the distance of the init/load height of the page for the entire duration.

EDIT:  I took the overflow suggestion and it works in fiddle, but if you notice, the words aren't falling at a the duration (slower because the page is shorter), they still fall as if the page is 3 times longer (and they are falling at different rates, which they shouldn't be)  They should all behave like "first" falling in unison

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

do what you're trying to achieve?

The following also might do, if you want to do that effect only in a part of the page:

```
#wordframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.word {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: Gloria Hallelujah;
}​

<div id="wordframe">
    <div class="word" cue="5">first</div>
    <div class="word" cue="10">second</div>
    <div class="word" cue="20">third</div>
    <div class="word" cue="20">fourth</div>
    <div class="word" cue="30">fifth</div>
    <div class="word" cue="35">sixth</div>
    <div class="word" cue="40">seventh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works on the fiddle, but not in my doc cuz I have a bunch of other stuff like animated footers n stuff.  thanks, I'll see if I can mess with that thought on the parent divs tho.

Comment: I just edited the original answer with a wrapper div. Just make sure, that the vertical size is limited.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle, doesn't work. hiding overflow on the body stopped the rendering of the expansion but not the behavior of the words (they were still acting like the height was expanding)

Comment: Then I probably didn't understand what you exactly tried to achieve.
Probably you should expose more of your html code, so the problem gets obvious.

Comment: Thanks mark for your time.  You can look at the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ETKYj/10/ it's the bare bones code and you can see the behavior.  All the words should be working like "first", falling all at the same rate over the entire duration.

Comment: I'm still not sure, but I saved two different solutions:
1st solution will put all words at the top of the wordframe and let them fall simultaneously (looks ugly, as they overlap): http://jsfiddle.net/XJxuJ/1/

2nd solution will leave the initial layout. Only the 1st item is animated, the others will move automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/DSAWQ/1/

Comment: wow, so adding the "px" and position:absolute sure did do a lot! THANKS –